# PM2 Cluster Mode. Execution on one process blocks the event loop on other processes as well

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using PM2 in cluster mode and have 2 instances of my node.js application running. I have some long executing cron jobs (about 30 seconds) that I am trying to run. I am placing an if statement before the execution of the cron jobs to ensure that they only run on the first process via

```
if (process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE === 0) {
    myCronFunction()
}
```

The goal was that since there are two processes, and PM2 should be load balancing them, if the cron job executes on process one, then process two would still be available to respond to the request. I am not sure what's going on, if PM2 is not successfully load balancing them, or what. But when my cron job executes on instance one, instance two is still not responding to requests until after the job on instance one finishes executing.

I'm not sure why that is. It is my understanding that they are supposed to be completely independent of one another.

Anyone have any ideas?